# Place div under a absolute-positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have tried to place 2 `<div>`s under one another with the style `position: absolute` for the first `<div>`. Unfortunately, I do not seem to be able to do so as the first `<div>` seem to be overlapping the second. My code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/1ega1/pen/JGVJVM).

Is there any way to position the second `<div>` below the first?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Calibri Light, Calibri, Ariel;
}
div#view {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFEB3B;
}
div h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
div h4#message {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
div h1 span {
  color: #616161;
}
div h1#end {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
div p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 30px;
}
div#signup {
  /* How to put this <div> below div#view? Is it possible? */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <!-- Birthday view -->
  <div id="view">
    <h1 id="start">Hello,<br/><span id="to">world</span>!</h1>
    <h4 id="message">How are you?</h4>
    <h1 id="end">From,<br/><span id="from">space</span></h1>
    <p>&darr;</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Signup -->
  <div id="signup">
    <h1>Whoops, align me at the bottom</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The absolute positioning is not ideal. Why do you need to use it? Also, when I run it I don't see any issue with the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div#view {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
 }

div#signup {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `div#view` to `position: absolute;` you are pulling it out of the normal document flow. Meaning that the other elements will arrange themselves as if the absolutely positioned element didn’t exist.

I believe your page has a structure problem. I would create a parent DIV to manage your background color and positioning, then your children DIV's to manage the content.

Comment: I think it's a little too complicated?

Comment: It's not too complicated, just not structured in a way that will let you accomplish what you want. 

I would structure it as such:

`<div id="content">`
  `<div id="view">`
  `</div>`
`</div>`

Answer (score -2):

> you can use position:relative and then adjust the position of div using margin,
>   by using div id and put it in proper position.
>   or you put body inside center    tag.

Comment: This might work if I am making a static webpage, but the content in `div#view` is going to be dynamic, so I do not think it might work as well.

Comment: Your post looks like you're quoting someone, but who? Also, please don't suggest introducing errors in the HTML.